# Smart quotes in Google Blogger

Tags: blogger, text-formatting

I would like to have Google Blogger automatically make the apostrophes and quotes in my posts curly, as word processors do. For example, I want to type this:

[image: straight quotes - bad]

and get this:

[image: curly quotes - good]

I mostly use Firefox on Mac OS X, but it would be nice if it worked on other systems as well. Currently I know how to type the curly quotes manually on the Mac, but that’s tedious and I make a lot of mistakes.

I know that WordPress does this in a postprocessing step, which is OK, but I’d really prefer a WYSIWYG approach directly in the composition box.

(And if you’re wondering how I got curly quotes in this question, it’s because I typed them manually as well.)